# Start a YouTube *direct link* video at a specific position?

Tags: youtube, webm

I used to use YT video in FLV format (itag 5) and I was able to start at a specific point in time by adding "&begin=xxxx" to the URL. 
I had to move to WEBM as FLV seems to be fully deprecated (itag 43) but I can't find a way to start at a given position.
I can't use HLS or DASH.
note: this is not about embedding a YT link in a page like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx. I know in that case I can use "&start=zzz". Here it's about the link to the file itself on goooglevideo.com sites

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for clarification, I know now this is not possible. You have to crawl through the webm format and then request the right chunk using HTTP offset. Works, but less convenient compare to what it was in the past